# Can I programmatically change the text of the Localizable.strings file?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I have Localizable.strings in English and Spanish. Inside the file I have some texts:

```
"hud_message" = "Loading...";
"accept_title" = "Accept";
"cancel_title" = "Cancel";
```

I want to change the text of the key "**hud_message**", Change it for "**please wait**"

**How is this possible?**

Comment: Why would you even want to do that?

Comment: Why would you even want to do that? x2

Comment: No, you cannot change the "Localizable.strings" file. What you should is just add another string for the "please wait" and then have logic that shows that string instead of the "hud_message" one.